# Find occurrence of dates day between two dates

Tags: php

I want to find occurrence of dates of a day between a date range.

> E.g. date1 = 04/12/2012 (Thursday) and date2 = 04/30/2012.

So PHP function should return two dates:

> 19/12/2012 (1st Thursday after start date) and 26/12/2012 (2nd Thursday 
>   after start date).

For large date range function should return 1st,2nd,3rd,4th....so on occurrence dates.

Comment: Hi Josh.  Thanks for your reply. I have tried to find all the intermediate dates between two dates but don't have idea about find particular dates of day.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting all dates for Mondays and Tuesdays for the next year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045736/getting-all-dates-for-mondays-and-tuesdays-for-the-next-year)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The duplicate listed in the comments ( [Getting all dates for Mondays and Tuesdays for the next year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045736/getting-all-dates-for-mondays-and-tuesdays-for-the-next-year) ) has a rather verbose answer. Here is a succinct solution using [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) with [Relative Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php):

```
// Initialize our dates to UNIX timestamps
$startDate = strtotime( 'next Tuesday', strtotime($startDate) );
$endDate= strtotime($endDate);

// Output all Tuesdays prior to our end date
while ($startDate < $endDate) {

    echo date('n/j/Y', $startDate ). "\n";

    // Get next Tuesday relative to last Tuesday
    $startDate = strtotime( 'next Tuesday', $startDate );
}
```

Using today (`$startDate`) and 2 months from today (`$endDate`) as an example, the above outputs:

```
4/17/2012
4/24/2012
5/1/2012
5/8/2012
5/15/2012
5/22/2012
5/29/2012
6/5/2012
```

[See it in action.](http://codepad.org/VWxDMnAa)

**Note**: Ensure you are using a [proper date format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) to receive accurate results.