# Get all year dates for a specific day

Tags: javascript, algorithm, date, getdate

Is there an algorithm [or a javascript code] that gets all the **dates** for a **specific day** in the year if we gave it a starting date ?

For Example:

**Input**:  Tuesday , Dec, 11 2012.

**Output**: Dec, 18 2012, Dec, 25 2012, Jan, 1, 2013 .... etc.

Comment: A good place to start would be <script type.... How about you add a loop for i = 0 to 364, incrementing a date that is appended to a string. Once you have some code post it here

Comment: I don't get why "Feb 1 2012" is there... Do you mean "Jan 1 2013"?

Comment: Hope this url helpful to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045736/getting-all-dates-for-mondays-and-tuesdays-for-the-next-year

Comment: @elclanrs Yes, I meant  Jan 2013, I'm sorry.

Comment: @anujarora Thanks I'll try to understand it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How hard can it be?

```
var d1 = new Date('Tuesday , Dec, 11 2012');

for (var i = 0; i < 365; i += 7) {
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 7)
    console.log(d1);  //outputs every tuesday for the next year
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rnnS8/5/)

Comment: WOW, I love your answer .. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to adeneo's answer. Beat me to it, but I'll still share it. =p

```
var getDaysInYear = function(day, year) {
    var startDate = new Date(day + " " + year);
    var date = startDate;
    var dates = [];

    while (date.getFullYear() == year) {
        dates.push(date.toDateString()); // change this to change the output
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + 1000 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    }

    return dates;
};

// Returns an array of whatever is in dates.push().
var dates = getDaysInYear("Tuesday", 2013);
console.log(dates);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rGtD2/1/)